# Which Infinite Series Manipulation Of ln(2) Is Correct

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations

Of these two algebraic manipulations of the series representation of $\ln(2)$, which is correct?

The first rearrangement is based on Dirichlet's manipulation on $\ln(2)$, which went something like this,

$$ \begin{align} 
\ln(2) = 1 - \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{3} -\dfrac{1}{4} +\dfrac{1}{5} - \dfrac{1}{6} + ...
\end{align}
$$

Split into three sets,

$$
1, \dfrac{1}{3}, \dfrac{1}{5}, ...
$$

$$
\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{1}{6}, \dfrac{1}{10}, ...
$$

$$
\dfrac{1}{4}, \dfrac{1}{8}, \dfrac{1}{12}, ...
$$

Recombine as,
$$ \begin{align}
\ln(2) &= \Bigg( 1 - \dfrac{1}{2}\Bigg )  - \dfrac{1}{4} + \Bigg (\dfrac{1}{3} - \dfrac{1}{6}\Bigg ) - \dfrac{1}{8} +... \\
 &= \dfrac{1}{2} - \dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac{1}{6}  - \dfrac{1}{8} + ... \\
 &= \dfrac{1}{2} \Bigg( 1 - \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{3} -\dfrac{1}{4} +...  \Bigg) \\
 &= \dfrac{1}{2} \ln(2)
\end{align}
$$

First manipulation,

$$ \begin{align}
\ln(2) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \\
  &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2n-1} \quad - \quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2n}  \\
  &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2n-1} \quad - \quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2(2n-1)} \quad - \quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2(2n)}  \\
  &= \dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2n-1} \quad - \quad \dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2n}  \\
  &= \dfrac{1}{2} \Bigg( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2n-1} \quad - \quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2n}  \Bigg ) \\
  &= \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}  \\
  &= \dfrac{1}{2} \ln(2) 
\end{align}
$$

Second manipulation,

$$\begin{align}
\ln(2) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \\
  &= \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}  \\
  &= \lim_{N \to \infty}  \Bigg( \sum_{n=1}^{\dfrac{N}{2}} \dfrac{1}{2n-1} \quad - \quad \sum_{n=1}^{\dfrac{N}{2}} \dfrac{1}{2n} \Bigg) \\
  &= \lim_{N \to \infty}  \Bigg( \sum_{n=1}^{\dfrac{N}{2}} \dfrac{1}{2n-1} \quad - \quad \sum_{n=1}^{\dfrac{N}{4}} \dfrac{1}{2(2n-1)} \quad - \quad \sum_{n=1}^{\dfrac{N}{4}} \dfrac{1}{2(2n)} \Bigg ) \label{ln2alg12} \\
  &= \lim_{N \to \infty}  \Bigg( \sum_{n=1}^{\dfrac{N}{4}} \dfrac{1}{2n-1} \quad + \quad \sum_{n=\dfrac{N}{4}+1}^{\dfrac{N}{2}} \dfrac{1}{2n-1} \quad - \quad \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\dfrac{N}{4}} \dfrac{1}{2n-1} \quad - \quad \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\dfrac{N}{4}} \dfrac{1}{2n} \Bigg ) \label{ln2alg13} \\
  &= \lim_{N \to \infty}  \Bigg( \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\dfrac{N}{4}} \dfrac{1}{2n-1} \quad + \quad \sum_{n=\dfrac{N}{4}+1}^{\dfrac{N}{2}} \dfrac{1}{2n-1} \quad - \quad \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\dfrac{N}{4}} \dfrac{1}{2n} \Bigg ) \\
  &= \lim_{N \to \infty}  \Bigg( \dfrac{1}{2} \Bigg( \sum_{n=1}^{\dfrac{N}{4}} \dfrac{1}{2n-1}\quad - \quad  \sum_{n=1}^{\dfrac{N}{4}} \dfrac{1}{2n} \Bigg ) \quad + \quad \sum_{n=\dfrac{N}{4}+1}^{\dfrac{N}{2}} \dfrac{1}{2n-1} \Bigg )  \\
  &= \lim_{N \to \infty}  \Bigg( \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\dfrac{N}{4}} \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \quad + \quad \sum_{n=\dfrac{N}{4}+1}^{\dfrac{N}{2}} \dfrac{1}{2n-1} \Bigg ) \\
  &= \dfrac{1}{2} \lim_{N \to \infty}  \Bigg( \sum_{n=1}^{\dfrac{N}{4}} \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \Bigg) \quad + \quad \lim_{N \to \infty} \Bigg( \sum_{n=\dfrac{N}{4}+1}^{\dfrac{N}{2}} \dfrac{1}{2n-1} \Bigg ) \\
  &= \dfrac{1}{2} \ln(2) \quad + \quad \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \Bigg ( \sum_{n=1}^{\dfrac{N}{4}} \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{N}{2}+2n-1} \Bigg ) \quad \quad  \text{(N divisible by 4)}
\end{align}
$$

Dirichlet performed the first manipulation and could not see why he got the result $\ln(2) = \dfrac{1}{2} \ln(2)$. He showed it to Riemann who resolved the problem by writing the Riemann Rearrangement Theorem that states that conditionally convergent series can be rearranged to sum to any desired value.

However, you can show the partial sums (created by a Delayed Inclusion Process)

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\dfrac{N}{4}} \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{N}{2}+2n-1} \quad \quad \text{(Ethereal Series)}$$

are non zero and increase in size. Computationally you can show the limit,

$$ \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \Bigg ( \sum_{n=1}^{\dfrac{N}{4}} \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{N}{2}+2n-1} \Bigg ) = \dfrac{1}{2} \ln(2)$$

So which manipulation is correct?

Comment: The first manipulation is incorrect starting at line 2 since $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2n}=\infty$$ Is this really your question?

Comment: This is perhaps the single ugliest usage of MathJax I have ever seen.  I don't understand why anyone would deliberately choose to typeset these summations like this.

Comment: "Etherial Series"?

Comment: @Did This splitting of denominators into odd and even sums is what Dirichlet and Riemann did, and many other mathematicians do. They do not see anything wrong with this type of manipulation.

Comment: @SimonCox Are you serious? Nothing could be farther from the truth, actually every serious curriculum on series spends quite some time to explain that "this type of manipulation" is  "wrong", very much so.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Typo meant "Ethereal Series" See [link](http://www.understanding-infinity.com/chap2sec2.php)

Comment: @Did As I said this is what Dirichlet and Riemann did except they just wrote down the first few terms of the series and used "..." notation. All I have done is express their manipulation algebraically. See [link](https://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_14/history%20of%20rearrangements.pdf) for an alternate method of deriving this result.

Comment: You know, you could just as easily have pasted the definition in: "An ethereal series is a dynamic series that is generated through the rearrangement of or combination of two or more series." Except, of course, there's nothing there to tell us what a "dynamic series" is.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Definition of "dynamic series" see [link](http://www.understanding-infinity.com/chap2sec1.php)

Comment: @SimonCox So... you are in fact alluding to the rearrangement theorem. Sorry but in no way is one supposed to write in this context anything like $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n-1}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n}$$ to use such a theorem. And this is quite fortunate since, as I already said, this expression reads $$\infty-\infty$$ which does not exist. So, again, a partial answer to your question asking "Of these two algebraic manipulations... which is correct?" is that the first one is definitely incorrect. (However... at this point, what you really mean to ask is most unclear.)

Comment: @Did I've edited the question to include Dirichlet's non algebraic manipulation of $\ln(2)$, I have followed his steps as best I can algebraically. So when he splits the series in to three sets this is equivalent to line 3 of the first manipulation, and I recombine them using his method to achieve the same result.

Comment: Yeah, and you are still missing (but do you wish to listen?) that these manipulations cannot apply to the whole series at once but only to one term after another...

Comment: I am listening. The main stumbling blocks for me are 1) if you say manipulation 1 is wrong then you are saying Dirichlet's non algebraic manipulation is wrong (and no one says this), 2) one of he main points of Riemann Rearrangement Theorem is the conditionally convergent series is split in to two series one containing the positive terms and the other the negative terms, each series sum to $\infty$ and $-\infty$ respectively see [link](https://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_14/history%20of%20rearrangements.pdf) for detail of why these sums have to be infinite

Comment: No, I won't see the link. Instead, I'll encourage you to edit all your idiosyncratic definitions into the body of your post, so everything is in one place, and readers don't have to go chasing links to work out what you're talking about.

Comment: Right, conjecture confirmed: you do not listen, probably because you came here mainly to "sell" this paper of yours. By the way, can you point at any place where Dirichlet would actually write $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2n-1} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2n}\ ?$$ I mean, D himself, not you rephrasing what D said as what you imagine he said...

Comment: Dirichlet split it in to three sets  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2n-1} \quad - \quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2(2n-1)} \quad - \quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2(2n)}$$   and this is the algebraic way of expressing this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since $\ln 2 \neq \frac{1}{2} \ln 2$, and $\ln 2 = \frac{1}{2} \ln 2 + \frac{1}{2} \ln 2$, you would expect the first manipulation to be wrong, and perhaps the second is correct.

Recall that series are not actually sums, but limits of partial sums, so $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n} := \lim_{n \to \infty} s_n, \quad \quad \text{where } s_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{(-1)^i}{i}$$

We say that the sum is *convergent* if the sequence $s_n$ tends to a limit as $n \to \infty$.

The first manipulation rearranges infinitely many terms of the sum, which doesn't *a priori* make sense in terms of the sequence $s_n$, and as the Riemann Rearrangement Theorem shows, never makes sense unless the series is absolutely convergent.

The second manipulation works on each term $s_n$, which is always ok to do.

Comment: Dirichlet and Riemann performed rearrangements as in the first manipulation but they just wrote down the first few terms of the series and used "..." notation. See [link](https://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_14/history%20of%20rearrangements.pdf) for an alternate method of deriving this result.

Comment: Those notes reach the same conclusion - rearranging conditionally convergent series can alter the sum of the series. It's true that Dirichlet and Riemann did such rearrangements, but it's also true that they found that such rearrangements do not preserve the answer. What is your definition of a "correct" manipulation?

Comment: The second manipulation is more rigorous than the first. A "correct" manipulation would be one that provides consistent results.

Comment: Yes, but also the second manipulation is _legal_, while the first is not. You are allowed to rearrange infinitely many terms in series if and only if the series is absolutely convergent. Otherwise, such rearrangements might affect the outcome, so aren't valid things to do.

Comment: Riemann did not say that rearrangement of conditional convergent series were invalid. He showed that a rearrangement can be forced to sum to any finite value. A consequence of this is that the commutative law for addition has to be suspended, his theorem does not explain why this is the case, it only shows a method for achieving a value.

Comment: The commutative law states that $a+b=b+a$, and it does not need to be suspended. The theorem shows that the extension of the law to $\sum^{\infty}a_i=\sum^{\infty}a_{\sigma(i)}$ is invalid, and the theorem explains that this is the case because any such extension leads to contradictions. I really don't see what you are getting at, Simon.